# Installing Silverlight 4 in Windows server 2012, Ria service applications not working

Tags: wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012

I have the flowing setup

- Windows server 2012 Standard
- IIS-8
- Ria services 1.0 sp1
- Silverlight 4

I need to make this applications work but I tried about anything to make this setup work. Any one know What i need to install to make Ria services work in this environment.

Already tried to install ria service on the server and using the option SERVER=true

I just keep getting the 404 when trying to connect to the server on web-config. I tried to include the wcf tracing on the web-config but the trace doesn't register anything.

Anyone have a step by step installation guild from a just installed server to a server that cans run ria service application of silverlight 4?

already tried everything here [WCF RIA Service deployment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869663/wcf-ria-service-deployment-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need the HTTP Activation feature installed for your IIS.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/6539af8b-96f1-4c4b-b03e-3973f3a5744f